# my query doesn't return the max from value from the sum of working hours of the month

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find name of that persons who worked most in a month. but the query doesn't returning max value from sum of value

I'm new in mysql

```sql
SELECT
  x.name, 
  sec_to_time(MAX(x.sum_time)) maximum 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    name, 
    SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ending_time) - TIME_TO_SEC(starting_time)) sum_time 
  FROM working_hours wh, employees
  WHERE wh.employees_id = employees.id 
  AND project_id IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY employees_id
) x
GROUP BY x.name;
```

this is my query. i want to show just name of that persons who worked most in a month. but it returns all persons who worked in a month

Comment: order by with limit? Can you add sample data as text in the question please

Comment: use the `having` clause then. `select x.name, sec_to_time(MAX(x.sum_time)) maximum from (blah blah blah)x group by x.name having sum_time=maximum;` change sum_time and maximum to same data types though.

Comment: 'Ahmar Yousaf'            | '21:45:00'
'Muzammil Hussain'    | '21:15:00'
'Hassan Arif'                | '17:00:00'
'Harris Shahid'             | '09:00:00'

This output is shown. But i want only tha name of that person who worked most

Comment: order by with no limit. because more than one employee can have same time

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Order by LIMIT -

```
SELECT X1.name, X1.maximum
FROM (SELECT name, SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ending_time) - TIME_TO_SEC(starting_time)) maximum
      FROM working_hours wh, employees
      WHERE wh.employees_id=employees.id
      GROUP BY name) X1
JOIN (SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ending_time) - TIME_TO_SEC(starting_time)) sum_time 
      FROM working_hours wh, employees
      WHERE wh.employees_id=employees.id 
      AND project_id is not null
      GROUP BY employees_id
      ORDER BY sum_time DESC
      LIMIT 1) X2 ON X2.sum_time = X1.maximum;
```

Comment: @AhmarYousaf, Try now.

Comment: It's working. but it's only giving me the one person. if more than one person have maximum time, then what I should do ?

Comment: @AhmarYousaf, May you please give it a try?

Comment: @AhmarYousaf, Can you please give it a try now?

Answer (score 0):

Try making these changes to your query:

- change `name` to `MAX(name)`
- qualify `employees_id` with `wh.employees_id`

```sql
SELECT
  x.name, 
  sec_to_time(MAX(x.sum_time)) maximum 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    MAX(name) AS name, 
    SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ending_time) - TIME_TO_SEC(starting_time)) sum_time 
  FROM working_hours wh, employees
  WHERE wh.employees_id = employees.id 
  AND project_id IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY wh.employees_id
) x
group by x.name;
```